# SQL group by get another table value by id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables these following tables:

| users |
| --- |
| id |
| name |
| car |

| cars |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

let's say I have these users

id: `1`, name: `Michael`, car: `1`

id: `2`, name: `Danny`, car: `2`

id: `3`, name: `Jennifer`, car: `1`

and these cars

id: `1`, name: `Audi`,

id: `2`, name `BMW`

I am trying to get how many each type of car the users have, so the result should be like:

| cars | cars count |
| --- | --- |
| Audi | 2 |
| BMW | 1 |

I am running the following command

```
SELECT u.car, c.name, COUNT('car count') FROM users u INNER JOIN cars c ON c.id = u.car GROUP BY c.id
```

which gives the following result

| cars | name | cars count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi | 2 |
| 2 | BMW | 1 |

How can I disregard the name column but to display the name inside the cars column (like I mentioned above)?

Comment: Just don't select it, if you don't want it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the cars return as `id` and I wanna display their name

Comment: You are already selecting and displaying the car name, are saying you are wanting to show the user's name? Perhaps you should include your expected output in your question.

Comment: @Andrew I want the cars column to display the names rather than the `id`, so the cars will be `Audi` and the count will be `2`, right now it returns its `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
SELECT c.name as cars, COUNT('car count') 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN cars c ON c.id = u.car 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    c.name as 'car', 
    COUNT('car count') 
FROM 
    users u 
INNER JOIN 
    cars c ON c.id = u.car 
GROUP BY 
    c.id
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed :)